# Multiple field query search without full text search

Tags: php, mysql

Query looks something like this:

```
$query = "
SELECT $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5 
FROM . $usertable 
WHERE $field1 = '$a' 
  AND $field2 = '$b'
  AND $field3 = '$c'
  AND $field4 = '$d'
  AND $field5 = '$e'
";
```

Now

- a is a varchar(20)
- b is a double
- c is an int
- d is an int
- e is a varchar(25)
- a - e ARE ALL USER INPUTS

**Full text search is not an option**, as a search must always return a result even if not an exact match.

Comment: Please format your code so people can read it. Also, your question feels to me a bit under-spec'd. All I know is that users submit all of the fields to search on (no comment on using this technique and if it should be used...), and that full text searches are not an option. And...?

Comment: Do you have a problem using `LIKE` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `LIKE`:

```
$query = "  
SELECT $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5  
FROM $usertable  
WHERE $field1 LIKE '%$a%'  
  AND $field2 LIKE '%$b%'  
  AND $field3 LIKE '%$c%'  
  AND $field4 LIKE '%$d%'  
  AND field5 LIKE '%$e%'  
";
```

The above solution only gives you result if all of search criteria are matched.
If you are looking for at least one is matched, use `OR` over `AND`.

```
$query = "  
SELECT $field1, $field2, $field3, $field4, $field5  
FROM $usertable  
WHERE $field1 LIKE '%$a%'  
  OR $field2 LIKE '%$b%'  
  OR $field3 LIKE '%$c%'  
  OR $field4 LIKE '%$d%'  
  OR field5 LIKE '%$e%'  
";
```

In both of the cases above, query may not return a result if none of the search criteria is matched.
Result would be an empty set.

Comment: Sorry about that Jared. And Ravinder, in this instance the LIKE feature isn't going to return a result. Please allow me to elaborate:

Let's say this query is looking for where we should go to dinner tonight as an example:

Comment: A = type of food
B = price
C = how many people
D = distance from location
E = environment type

Now if the query doesn't find an exact match in all 5 fields, it is returning no result. The LIKE feature unfortunately in this case will not work.

Comment: @CWF010 Well, I was aware of this issue while posting my answer. I just gave an alternative for a full text search. We can use `OR` over `AND` and among the results fetched, you have to select the best for you.